# How do I create an iterator over a recursive data structure in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang, recursive-datastructures

I have a tree structure and currently I am trying to return an iterator that iterates over the elements of the datastructure so that my function can accept a block.

I have currently reduced my code to this:

```rb
# tree.cr
class Tree
  property children : Array(Tree)

  def initialize(@value : Int32)
    @children = [] of Tree
  end

  def add(child : Tree)
    @children << child
  end

  def each_leaf : Iterator(Int32)
    Iterator.chain [{@value}.each, @children.each.flat_map(&.each_leaf)]
  end
end

root = Tree.new 3
root.add Tree.new 1
root.add Tree.new 5

p root.each_leaf.to_a # no output from here
p "hi" # no output from here either
```

Interestingly the code snippet above simply terminates, and the second print `p "hi"` doesn't get executed either.
Would love to hear pointers on how this code could be corrected. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here are some details of the executing environment

- Crystal Version: v1.7.2
- Command: `crystal run tree.cr`
- Output: `Program received and didn't handle signal TRAP (5)`
- System: M1 Macbook Pro, Monterey 12.6

Comment: The code works as expected for me. It prints `[3, 1, 5]` and `hi`.
How do you run it?

Comment: Oh! that's interesting. I have it as a build target in my shard.yml, and I run it with `shards run tree`

Comment: Can you share exactly what steps you do? What happens for that command? Just no output at all?

Comment: Added more information in the original question, tried executing with `crystal run`. It seems to me that there is just some issue with using iterators on my computer. Recently I had another instance where `ary.select {...}.map{...}` returned a different value from `ary.each.select{...}.map{...}.to_a`. I'm going to file an issue on the github repo.

Comment: I get the same behavior ("Program received and didn't handle signal TRAP (5)") on an M1 Macbook Pro  running Ventura 13.1.

Comment: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/13037